# ios9 Safari miscalculating sum

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ios9, ecmascript-5

I have some code that calculates the sum of key/values in a hash in a loop.  It appears to be calculating the sum in a different manner on ios9 Safari compared with anywhere else.  Although I can find a way to fix this individual use case, we use this type of syntax throughout our large code base, so I am looking for some understanding of

1. why this is happening in ios9
2. if there is a way to globally fix it that would be applicable to all objects that might have a Vue `__ob__` object on them.

Try the code out here: https://liveweave.com/kKo88G. I also pasted it below:

```
// Define a hash
var totalItems, sum, type, value
totalItems = {}
totalItems['0'] = 3

// This definition of __ob__ is done dynamically by Vue,
// but I include it here by way of example of what breaks in ios9
totalItems.__ob__ = new Object()
Object.defineProperty(totalItems, '__ob__', {
    enumerable: false,
    writable: true,
   configurable: true
  });

// Loop through the hash
sum = 0
for (type in totalItems) {
  value = totalItems[type];
  sum += value;
}

// sum is 6 in ios9 Safari -- it loops through the '0' key twice 
// sum is 3 in all other browsers and newer ios versions!
```

**UPDATE:**

After investigating further, this appears to be a bug in Safari on ios9 devices.  It applies both to hashes with the key '0' in them and to arrays.  It only seems to be an issue with `for-in` loops.  `.forEach`, `.reduce`, etc. work fine. https://liveweave.com/znUFU2 showcases this. Refresh the page a couple of times if liveweave is slow to load at first.  js fiddle/codepen/etc. don't work on ios9 at the moment. I have reported this to Apple.

Comment: Looks like Safari on iOS9 had other issues that seem related to yours: https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/issues/364#issuecomment-230349756

Answer (score 0):

Usually using **for ... in** is not a good idea. I believe your issue is related to that.

You can use **for ... of ** or do a regular **for** loop.

See a detailed explanation of what happens with for ... in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/500565/1993956)