# How to create a babel plugin for internal use

Tags: babeljs

How do we use a babel plugin that is *not* already accepted in a babel repository?  I had trouble finding this answer reading through the babel plugin documentation.

We are interested in writing a babel plugin for `for...in` loops to address a bug in ios9 ([ios9 Safari miscalculating sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52857259/ios9-safari-miscalculating-sum)). Although we would be happy to contribute it to the babel community, I was also wondering if it doesn't get accepted or isn't ready for general consumption, how to start using and testing it locally.

Comment: if i don't miss understood your question have you tryed to write in to webpack as a new plagin?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's possible to make use of custom babel plugins that you can host on git.

You can refer to https://github.com/jamiebuilds/babel-handbook/blob/master/translations/en/plugin-handbook.md for learning how you can develop and test your babel plugin locally.

Once you have developed the plugin, you can add a dependency for it in your project's `package.json` file.

Note that if you plan to make the plugin repository private, you'd have to create a personal access token (for Github) to allow npm to fetch repository contents. In that case, the example entry in your `package.json` file would be as follows:

`"babel-plugin-transform-for-of-loop": "git+https://{token}:x-oauth-basic@github.com/username/babel-plugin-transform-for-of-loop"`

Whatever package name that you pick for your plugin, you will need to add a reference for it in the `.babelrc` file. For this example, it would be as follows:

```
{
  ...
  "plugins": [
    "babel-plugin-transform-for-of-loop"
  ]
}
```

With that done, you should simply run `npm install` and your plugin would become active for your project.